# can we have a default parameter in java akka http?

Tags: java, http, akka

like below code

```
                 post(() -> route(
                    pathPrefix("scheduleStatus", () ->
                            path("send", () ->
                                    parameter("type", type ->
                                            entity(Jackson.unmarshaller(Car.class), car -> {
                                                return complete(car.getColor());
                                            })
                                    )

                            )
                    ))
```

can we have default value for type? like we think default car type is bmw etc?
how can we achieve this in java akka http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akkording to [the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#optional-parameter) you cannot do it with `parameter()` - you need to use `parameterOptional()`:

```
    post(() -> route(
        pathPrefix("scheduleStatus", () ->
            path("send", () ->
                parameterOptional("type", type ->
                    entity(Jackson.unmarshaller(Car.class), car -> {
                        return complete(car.getColor());
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: I don't have the credit for vote a answer...

Comment: @LizzyMM if this answers your question you can mark the answer as "accepted"